# Why does indicator-sound-service use so much memory?

Tags: sound, 15.04, indicator, xfce, memory-usage

What can it possibly be doing to require that much memory?
Thanks.
-Erik

```
charm /etc/xdg/xfce4 282# cat /etc/lsb-release  
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu  
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.04  
DISTRIB_CODENAME=vivid 



STAT    VSZ  EUID TT       PID %CPU COMMAND  
S+    16680     0 pts/6   7650  0.0 grep -E --color=auto indicator.sound|UID  
Ssl  479372   119 ?       1562  0.0 indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service  
Ssl  627320  1000 ?       2470  0.0 indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
```